# change display property on hover

Tags: jquery, css, properties, hover

I would like to change the CSS `display` property as I move over another element.
I tried to accomplish this with `jQuery` like:

```
$( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).hover(function() {
  $(".mega").css("display", "show");

});
```

but my element which is define in `html` like `<div class="mega" style="display: none;">` still does not show up, why not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no valid `value` available with `display` property called `show`. You may want to write this  `$(".mega").css("display", "block");` but that can be simply written as `$(".mega").show()`

Try,

```
$( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).hover(function() {
  $(".mega").show();
});
```

---

For showing and hiding the elements on mouse hover.

```
  $( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).hover(function() {
      $(".mega").show();
    },function(){
      $(".mega").hide();
  });
```

Comment: Can you also tell me, how do I hide `.mega` again when the cursor leaves the element?

Answer (score 1):

can try this :

```
$( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).hover(function() {
  $(".mega").css("display", "block");

});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, on mouseover and mouse leave will be useful.

```
$('.li.megamenu-li-first-level').mouseover(function(){
if ($('.mega').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.mega').css("display","block");
}
```

});

$('.li.megamenu-li-first-level').mouseleave(function(){
    if ($('.mega').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('.mega').css("display","none");`enter code here`
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

This is the end worked best for me:

```
$( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).mouseover(function() {
  $(".mega").show();
});
$( "li.megamenu-li-first-level" ).mouseleave(function() {
  $(".mega").hide();
});
```

Thank you all for the help, I was able to use bits and pieces from everyone!